# Make a group of sprites ripple when another sprite collides with them?

Tags: sprite-kit, core-animation, skspritenode

I have created a basic animation that consists of a 3x3 grid with square sprites dropping into this grid from the top, then dropping out once the grid is full.

I would like to send a ripple through the sprites already present in the grid when a new one joins them (from the origin of the new sprite). I have not used SpriteKit before so am a little unsure of where to go from here; do I need to use collision masks? How do I cause that collision to be passed through the sprites?

Any pointers would be appreciated.